# Тестирование клиента и сервера с помощью genymotion

Tags: android, java, тестирование

При тестировании клиента и сервера с помощью genymotion сервер не получает сообщения клиента, в то время как при использовании telnet сервер получает сообщения. В чем, кроме клиента может быть проблема, как её можно решить. Или если проблема в клиенте, как можно протестировать клиента без сервера?

Comment: Скорее всего это я чего-то не знаю, но все таки - а каким образом вы сравниваете использование telnet с genymotion?

Comment: IP-адрес сервера, на который вы ходите с GenyMotion — это не 127.0.0.1?
Сервер — в локальной или глобальной сети? Если второе — открываются ли другие сайты через браузер с GenyMotion?

Answer (score 1):

Перефразирую вопрос: как можно протестировать клиента без сервера? Telnet использую для отправки сообщений серверу(моб. устройства). Если что , клиент и сервер - написаны.

Вопрос на будущее, может есть какие инструменты и не можно не писать заглушки?

Сервер в глобальной сети. IP-адрес сервера не 127.0.0.1. Я использую соединение не для отображения информации с сайтов, а для передачи информации от клиента к серверу через TCP протокол.